# Solr 3.5: Mutliple values encountered for non multivalued field

Tags: xml, exception, solr, xml-parsing, schema

I have defined a multivalued field in my Solr schema.xml file to implement the auto-complete feature as follows:

```
<field name="name" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="nameac" type="autocomplete" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="name" dest="nameac"/>
```

However, i see an error like this:

> ERROR [org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore] (http-executor-threads - 639)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=ffff] multiple
>   values encountered for non multiValued field nameac: [abc def, abc
>   def]

I expected that the attribute `multiValued="true"` should have handled this.

Please suggest.

Regards.

Comment: were the configuration changed without restarting the solr server ? please restart and check

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common error when we change our configuration for field names. 
Your change to the "schema.xml" has not been reflected in the Solr configuration because when you start your server, configuration files are loaded at that time only and any further changes don't get reflected.

So, as @Jayendra suggested, shut down your server and restart it again to load the changes in the configuration.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same issue - restarting the Solr server didn't help.